# iTunes Connect Localization (add english words to other countries)

Tags: ios, localization, app-store, app-store-connect

The apps default language is english.
When submitting an app/or an update and adding languages I thought about adding english keywords also to other languages (f.e. france).

Example

**ENG**:

> "delivery,food,order,meals,restaurant,burger,fries,pizza........."

**FR**:

> "delivery,food,order,meals,restaurant,livraison,nourriture,ordre,pizza"

Because I am also not from an english country, but most often I search in the App Store by entering english words such as "racing" and others.

**Do I need to add the english keywords also to the other languages or will they also be considered by the App Store search (regardless of the country), so that I can add ONLY french words  ?**

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience, you do not need to add English keywords to the keywords of a different language/localization. We did a couple of tests (we have more than 20 apps on the Store at the moment) and it seems that somehow they automatically added. But I'm afraid no one can tell for sure.

Having that said you should always make sure to use the 100 characters for keywords. So when you only have 80 characters for French, you should better "fill" them up with English or more relevant keywords/synonyms etc.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience, with a little luck more people will share their opinions or knowledge (or communicate with apple ;) ) so that we will know for sure.